# Angular Typescript - Use existing values in FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my app I have a list and a form for changing the values in the list.

An input field from my form looks like this for example:

```
<input matInput id="nameInput" formControlName="name" value="{{person.name}}">
```

And my list displays data like this:

```
 <h3 mat-subheader>Name</h3>
      <mat-list-item> {{person.name}} </mat-list-item>
```

As you can see I use `{{person.name}}` as value in my form input field. This means the already existing value should be used as a value in the input field and it is actually being displayed correctly in the form input field.
Except it doesn't recognize that there's already input in that field, I know this cause my form disables the sumbit button unless there's more than 3 characters in the input field. How can I tell my form to use the already existing  value of `{{person.name}}` and all it's characters?

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly i think you should be using setValue or patchValue.
so if u have some form, for example:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
     name: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

you can set it's value by calling

```
this.form.patchValue(this.person); //or setValue()
```

and your model "person" holds always current value for "name" property

**edit:** 
define your model with some properties:

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}
```

then create some form and new Person:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
     name: ['', Validators.required],
     surname: ['', Validators.required],
});
const person = new Person;
person.name = "John";
person.surname = "Doe";
//or get your model from db - thats for you to decide :)
```

and with those 2 elements you can "populate" your form with model values:

```
this.form.setValue(this.person);
```

Comment: That makes sense! But how could I set it for each input field individually? For example in the 'name' input field I always want to have {{person.name}} and in 'E-Mail' it would be {{person.email}}

Comment: check my edit :) Your model can have multiple properties - model prop to form field